# Adding a Excel Table to the end of a Sharepoint site in access

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint-2010

So I have a table on a sharepoint site that another party updates with new items (spreadsheet style)

I also (currently) have an excel sheet that has reviews of each item that is on said sharepoint site.

The trick is things are added and deleted from the sharepoint site and I need to be able to track what is added and what is deleted so I know what I need to review. Orginally I did this on excell but I had to realign the reviews when things were added or taken out of the sharepoint site (a lengthy process) so someone suggested access but I am having issues trying to find a good tutorial that answer how I could do this.

my thought was to create access database that imported the columns from the sharepoint site and that I could just append more collumns to the end of it to add in my review comments. Would this work?

ultimately I would like to have my reviews put up on another sharepoint site.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint can send emails when things change.

If you want to know how to see sharepoint data in MsAccess you can see [sharepoint-msaccess-synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096382/sharepoint-msaccess-synchronization):